# using any account for offchain worker signed transaction

Tags: extrinsic, account, offchain-worker

I'm trying to implement the following sequence:

1. Alice calls extrinsicA
2. extrinsicA calls off-chain worker
3. off-chain worker invokes an external service
4. off-chain worker uses Alice for a signed transaction to call extrinsicB

And I would like that when Bob does the same call to extrinsicA, it is him that the off-chain worker uses for the signed transaction to call extrinsicB.

However, I'm hitting a wall because [all accounts suitable to call a signed transaction from off-chain must be "injected"](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/offchain-workers/offchain-transactions/#sending-signed-transactions):

```rust
    sp_keystore::SyncCryptoStore::sr25519_generate_new(
        &*keystore,
        node_template_runtime::pallet_your_ocw_pallet::KEY_TYPE,
        Some("//Alice"),
    )
```

But this is a huge limitation. I would like that both Alice and Bob are able to perform the sequence without knowing in advance that they are going to do it or not.

Moreover, even if I had all the accounts injected, I'm not understanding how to select the appropriate one to sign the transaction:

```rust
let public_key = ???
let signer = Signer::<T, T::AuthorityId>::all_accounts().with_filter(vec![public_key]);
```

I have saved in the indexed storage the `T::AccountId` of the initiator (being Alice or Bob), but I don't see a way to recover the public key out of that.

- Is it possible to somehow inject the account in the keystore upon call to extrinsicA or it only works at chain bootstrap ?
- Can I recover an account public key from its `T::AccountId` or is there another way to use `with_filter` to identify the originator of the call to extrinsicA ?

Comment: This does not sound like an appropriate use of offchain workers. Why does an offchain worker need to be involved at all? In general, it does not sound like what you want is possible.

Comment: I've edited the question to display the fact that the off-chain worker would be used to invoke an external service that validates whether extrinsicB should be called or not. But I understand that I might need to rethink this logic. Still it would be useful if you could provide an example of `with_filter`, I haven't found any